# How can I show data on mysql with nodejs and expressjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, express

app.js

```
function showConnect(req, res){

    mysql_crawl.query('SELECT full_price, discount_price, quantity, prod_link, images, prod_desc, status FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE MATCH(data_index) AGAINST("ครีม") LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, rows){
    res.render('product.html',{related: rows})

    })
```

product.html

```
<%
for (var i of related){
%>
<%= i %>
<%
    }
%>
```

result on product.html

```
[object Object] [object Object]
```

How can i show all of each data in product.html (full_price, discount_price, quantity, prod_link, images, prod_desc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[object Object] is the default toString result. What you can do is use JSON.stringify() or explicitly state what you want to display, like i.quantity, i.image etc.

```
<table>
<% for(var i=0; i < related.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= related[i].full_price %></td>
     <td><%= related[i].discount_price%></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```